# Error "Property 'children' is missing in type 'VNode<any>' but required in type 'ReactPortal'" in Typescript Preact Redux application built using Vite

Tags: typescript, redux, react-redux, preact

I am trying to build a `Typescript`-`Preact`-`Redux` application using `Vite` but the main.tsx file:

```js
import { render } from "preact"
import { Provider } from "react-redux"


render(
    <Provider>
        <div />
//      ^^^^^^^
    </Provider>
, document.getElementById("app") as HTMLElement)
```

...has the following type error for `<div />`:

```
Type 'Element' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.
  Property 'children' is missing in type 'VNode<any>' but required in type 'ReactPortal'.ts(2322)
index.d.ts(166, 9): 'children' is declared here.
Provider.d.ts(19, 5): The expected type comes from property 'children' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ProviderProps<AnyAction, unknown>'
(property) JSXInternal.IntrinsicElements.div: JSXInternal.HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>
```

Is it possible to config this to work correctly or should I give up on `preact` and use `react`?

vite.config.ts

```js
import { defineConfig } from "vite"
import preact from "@preact/preset-vite"

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [preact()],
})
```

package.json

```json
{
  "name": "monitor",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "tsc && vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "1.9.5",
    "preact": "10.13.2",
    "react-redux": "8.0.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@preact/preset-vite": "2.5.0",
    "typescript": "5.0.2",
    "vite": "4.3.9"
  }
}
```

tsconfig.json

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2020",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "lib": ["ES2020", "DOM", "DOM.Iterable"],
    "skipLibCheck": true,

    /* Bundler mode */
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "allowImportingTsExtensions": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "jsxImportSource": "preact",

    /* Linting */
    "strict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true
  },
  "include": ["src"],
  "references": [{ "path": "./tsconfig.node.json" }]
}
```

Comment: Have you set `"skipLibCheck": true` in your `tsconfig.json` as [Preact's docs say to do](https://preactjs.com/guide/v10/typescript/#typescript-preactcompat-configuration)? Unrelated, but remove `preact-compat`; [it's only for v8 and older](https://www.npmjs.com/package/preact-compat).

Comment: Thanks @rschristian I have removed the `preact-compat` and checked the tsconfig.json and it does have `"skipLibCheck": true`.  Do you have any other thoughts on where to explore next?  The rest of the application seems to work without problem.  Maybe a quick hack is to just silence this false error?

Comment: Adding the [`preact/compat` path aliases](https://preactjs.com/guide/v10/typescript/#typescript-preactcompat-configuration) might work? Otherwise, can't go wrong with `// @ts-ignore`